# MySQL and a checkout system. Due, overdue, available

Tags: mysql

EDIT: I'm not interested in the current status of the book. This is for a historical record of the various checkouts.

And actually, the whole question is probably so malformed as to be unanswerable. Yet I got an answer anyway, which is nice. I was mostly looking for that `WHEN` -> `THEN` structure.

---

I have `books` which can be checked out. There's a field for `date_out`, `date_due` and `date_returned`

Using those three fields, I'd like to be able to select the id and then status for each `book` where status is an int meaning "checked out," "overdue" or "available"

That is:

```
\-----------------\
|  ID    | status |
|-----------------|
|  1     |    0   |
|  2     |    2   |
|  3     |    1   |
-------------------
```

Where 0 = available, 1 = out and 2 = overdue (or whatever, I don't actually care what the values represent, so long as they return as int).

I suspect this is an easy question, but I lack the SQL knowledge to even start Googling.

Thanks!

Edited for clarity, maybe.

Comment: How you're handling the books? I mean, you have a system or some control panel?

Comment: This question is not fully formed enough.  It seems like you are struggling with even determining your basic schema.

Comment: As a side note, you may want to consider the type [`ENUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) for status. It seems like an appropriate use case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id,
CASE 
  WHEN date_returned>=date_due AND date_returned>=date_out THEN 0
  WHEN date_due>=date_out AND date_due>date_returned THEN 2
  WHEN date_out>date_due AND date_out>date_returned THEN 3
  ELSE 4 END as status
FROM books
```

Comment: Upon reflection, I realize that my question sucked, but this is still essentially the answer I was looking for. So that's really great. Thanks!